# Horde on CentOS 5: Can't send outbound message?

Tags: centos

My setup is local install so I don't expect it to receive emails from the internet. However I do expect it to be able send messages to the internet, but it doesn't seem like it. I have tried setting up on FreeBSD before and it was able to do so but I wasn't involved in the setting of the machine though. I was just tasked to setup Horde... Any insights please????

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed the excerpt of your postfix log files.

If your internet connection is of the residential kind, your internet provider is likely to have blocked outgoing smtp traffic.

Many ISP's expect you to use their outgoing smtp server to send mail, and not your own server. That way the machines of their customers can't be abused to send spam.

See the `relayhost` parameter in the postfix configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Centos 5 has SELinux enabled by default. Use the command `getenforce` to determine whether or not SELinux is enabled.

If SELinux is enabled you need to change the security settings for the web server. By default the web server daemon and any scripts it runs can't make any network connections, and you need one to send e-mail.

Depending on the mechanism used by Horde enabling mail functionality may be sufficient:

```
setsebool httpd_can_sendmail=on
```

or you need to allow more general network access.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=on
```

Comment: I think it can't be the problem because I have disabled iptables already before I posted here.

Comment: iptables is something completely different from SELinux. 

Run the command getenforce. 

If SELinux is disabled you will KNOW that you don't have to look there. On the other hand is SELinux is enabled it's very well possible that it blocks Horde from sending mail. And when SELiux blocks sending email, it won't appear in the apache error logs as a helpful SELinux error.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have an SMTP server installed and running on the Horde server.  Easiest way to check this is from an SSH session on the Horde server:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

If an SMTP server isn't running you'll get "connection refused" - in this case install something like Sendmail from your package repository.

Comment: Yup it's working. Actually my server can send and receive locally. However if I use it to send to the internet say email@gmail.com it does not send anything or that email does not receive any email...

Comment: tail -f /var/log/maillog while you try to send mail to the world, What does the log say?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're just being bounced as spam? Try sending a test email via telnet and see if it works.

You firstly need to find the MX for the domain you're sending to; in the case of gmail.com they are as follows:

```
 gmail.com  mail exchanger = 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
 gmail.com  mail exchanger = 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
 gmail.com  mail exchanger = 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
 gmail.com  mail exchanger = 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
 gmail.com  mail exchanger = 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Connect to one of these and type each of the below commands:

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp.in.1.google.com 25
EHLO yourdomain.com
MAIL FROM: user@yourdomain.com
RCPT TO: someuser@gmail.com
DATA
Subject: Test
Test
.
```

If you get an error message, that's your problem. If it goes through okay, the problem is likely to be with Horde - if this is the webmail client I'm thinking of, check your HTTP error log

Comment: After checking /var/log/maillog I found out that it can't connect to gmail or any email servers. Here's the log: http://pastebin.com/7Wg5HTZz. 

Could it be because my IP is dynamic? I read somewhere else that gmail and other don't allow receiving messages coming from dynamic IP address...